# What is the meaning of error message: The return type is incompatible

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to create the `entrySet()` method for a custom HashMap. I've attached both my entry class, called `MyEntry`, and my `entrySet()` method.

I receive the error:

> The return type is incompatible with `Map<K,V>.entrySet()`

... and the return type is underlined in red. I don't understand what this is expressing.

```
@Override   
public Set<HashMap<K,V>.MyEntry<K, V>> entrySet(){  
if (entrySetView != null) return entrySetView;
    else return entrySetView = new AbstractSet<HashMap<K,V>.MyEntry<K,V>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<HashMap<K,V>.MyEntry<K, V>> iterator() {
            return new HashIterator<HashMap<K,V>.MyEntry<K, V>>() {
                @Override
                public HashMap<K,V>.MyEntry<K, V> next() {
                    return nextEntry();
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return HashMap.this.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            HashMap.this.clear();
        }
    };
}

public class MyEntry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>{
    private K key;
    private V value;
    private MyEntry<K,V> next;
    private int hash;

    public MyEntry() {
        counter++;
    }

    public MyEntry(K key, V value, MyEntry<K,V> next, int h) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
        this.hash = h;
        counter++;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof MyEntry))
            return false;
        MyEntry entry = (MyEntry)o;
        Object k1 = getKey();
        Object k2 = entry.getKey();
        if (k1 == k2 || (k1 != null && k1.equals(k2))) {
            Object v1 = getValue();
            Object v2 = entry.getValue();
            if (v1 == v2 || (v1 != null && v1.equals(v2)))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setKey(K key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Object setValue(Object val) {
        V oldValue = value;
        value = (V) val;
        return oldValue;
    }

    public MyEntry<K,V> getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(MyEntry<K,V> n) {
        this.next = n;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "{" + getKey() + "," + getValue() + "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `entrySetView` which you are returning?

Comment: is your class called `HashMap`? If so, rename it to `MyHashMap` to reduce confusion.

Comment: The `.entrySet() ` is a method of a Map object, not the Map.Entry interface.

Comment: Set<HashMap<K, V>.MyEntry<K, V>> is the type of entrySetView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`entrySet` of the `Map` interface has a return type of `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>`, so you can't return a `Set<HashMap<K,V>.MyEntry<K, V>>`.

`Set<HashMap<K,V>.MyEntry<K, V>>` is not a sub-interface of `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>`.

I believe something like this should work (you might have to change the type of `entrySetView` as well):

```
@Override   
public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet(){  
  if (entrySetView != null) 
    return entrySetView;
  else 
    return entrySetView = new AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
            return new HashIterator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
                @Override
                public Map.Entry<K, V> next() {
                    return nextEntry();
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return HashMap.this.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            HashMap.this.clear();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that I do not use my custom entry class at all in the entryset() method?

Comment: @19kate96 Not at all. Your `nextEntry()` can still return a `HashMap<K,V>.MyEntry<K, V>` (assuming that class implements `Map.Entry<K,V>`). The important thing is that any methods that return an entry will have a `Map.Entry<K,V>` return type.